# Put menus and title on the same line (Electron)

Tags: electron, desktop-application

I want to put menus and title on the same line.
But my app has 2 lines like the following snapshot.

[image]

Any ideas to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with frameless browser windows and, for example, the custom-titlebar-plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-electron-titlebar

This replaces the normal titlebar from the operating system by a rendered one and then you're free to style/arrange it like you want.

Comment: This is just what I wanted!
Thank you so much!